# GUI options for emulator c++

Tags: c++, user-interface, emulation

I want to create a Gameboy emulator which runs directly from the exe file, in a similar fashion to visualboy advance. I was wondering in terms of creating a GUI interface for the emulator what would be the best option to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want a way to do 2D rendering?  If so there are numerous ways.  wxWidgets (as suggested), QT or SDL provide easy cross platform options.

Otherwise you could do it in any number of platform specific ways from using Windows GDI to using D3D11 or whatever platform rendering choices you have available.

Comment: Based on the question, I'd use something with back-buffering.

Answer (score 1):

[wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org). It's cross-platform, easy to use, and has great documentation.